Request failed "404 Not Found" when installing packages
NB: Adding this Q&A because none of the Q&As related to Request failed "404 Not Found" mention what solved the error for me.
Running yarn install or npm install results in the following error: screenshot of command line
Tried this and similar resolutions:
Installing package npm fails with 404

In my case the problem was that I was trying to install a private NPM package without being logged in to NPM.
To resolve:
Run npm login and follow the prompts.
